# Running Angular e2e tests using GitHub Actions throws "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, github-actions

I'm experimenting with GitHub actions and trying to run Angular e2e tests in this CI workflow.

I'm using the default project created by the Angular CLI, and only made modifications around the Protractor configuration. On the GitHub side I'm using the default workflow for Node.js and Azure, but for troubleshooting I removed all Azure related steps, so it's just trying to run the e2e tests.

My sample code is available here: https://github.com/DanielSzentimrey-Harrach/ng-e2e-ci-dummy

When I run the CI job I get the following error:

```
"unknows error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"
```

After googling this error I understand it's a problem with how e2e tests are running in a container, but I didn't find any way to resolve this within GitHub Actions. Most posts talk about adding various parameters to the Protractor configuration. I've tried the below ones, and their various permutations, but still no luck:

- --no-sandbox
- --disable-dev-shm-usage
- --disable-gpu
- --remote-debugging-port=9222
- --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [docs](https://angular.io/cli/e2e) should be not `--protractor-config=`  ...  but `--protractorConfig`
or better set the config in angular.json by e2e configuration, as e.g. 'ci'.
Then run `npm run e2e -- -c=ci`
[example project](https://github.com/filipesilva/ng-github-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)